# Соединение на ICMP

Tags: c++, icmp

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите, Если слать по очереди несколько пакетов по icmp протоколу, может ли измениться очередность получения этих пакетов на сервере? Я имею в виду, может ли пакет b, добраться до сервера быстрее пакета a, если пакет a отправили раньше?

Comment: В глобальной сети (с множеством роутеров) такое возможно. В локальной (оба устройства подключены к одному switch) практически нет.

Answer (score 1):

В RFC 792 и 950 об этом afaik ничего не говорится. Доставка пакетов вообще не гарантируется (вспомните команду `ping`).

Словом, такой гарантии FIFO для пакетов ICMP нет.

На всякий случай оговорюсь еще раз - afaik. Но вряд ли такое требование вообще выполнимо в протоколе без надежной передачи.